# CoffeeScript + JQuery infinite callback loop

Tags: jquery, callback, coffeescript

We have the following CoffeeScript code. The get_job_status function retrieves (via AJAX) the status of a task running at the Python backend. Then it passes the task status/result to the get_job_status function. The code should keep checking the task status on a regular basis until it changes from  "running" to "success". The problem is, when the backend says the task status is "success", the code below keeps checking it indefinitely (endless loop).

This code was working normally untile we made some changes. Now we are stuck for days trying to fix this issue.

```
window.get_job_status = (id_envio, id_barra_progresso) ->

    console.log "ID envio em get_job_status: " + id_envio

    unless id_envio of window.contadorErros
        window.contadorErros[id_envio] = Number(0)

    informacoes_adicionais =
        id_barra_progresso: id_barra_progresso
        id_envio: id_envio

    dados_enviar = JSON.stringify(
        id_envio: id_envio
    )


    ajax_verifica_status = $.ajax(
        type: "POST"
        url: "/resultadojobrqenvio"
        data: dados_enviar
        cache: false
        timeout: 3000
        context: informacoes_adicionais
    )


    ajax_verifica_status.fail (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
        id_envio = String(this.id_envio)
        id_barra_progresso = String(this.id_barra_progresso)

        console.log 'O GET request enviado via JQuery.ajax solicitando ao backend o status do job de envio de e-mails
                agrupados  com ID: "' + id_envio + '") FALHOU. Detalhes:\nHTTP Status: ' + textStatus +
                '\nTexto resposta HTTP: '+ jqXHR.responseText + '\nErro do JQuert.ajax:  ' + errorThrown


        console.log 'IdBarraProcStr: "' +id_barra_progresso + '"'

        $selector_barra_progresso = $('#' +id_barra_progresso)

        $selector_barra_progresso.width '100%'
        $selector_barra_progresso.text "ERRO!"
        $selector_barra_progresso.removeClass()
        $selector_barra_progresso.addClass "progress-bar progress-bar-custom-vermelho"

        window.contadorErros[id_envio] += 1

        unless window.contadorErros[id_envio] > 5
            setTimeout (-> get_job_status id_envio, id_barra_progresso), 2000
        else
            console.log 'Ocorreram 5 erros consecutivos no GET request enviado via JQuery.ajax solicitando ao backend o
                status do job do RQ "' + tipo_operacao + '" referente ao arquivo arquivo "' + nome_arquivo_pai +
                '" (ID: "' + id_relatorio + '") FALHOU. Detalhes:
                \nHTTP Status: ' + textStatus + '\nTexto resposta HTTP: '+ jqXHR.responseText + '\nErro do JQuert.ajax:  ' + errorThrown


    ajax_verifica_status.done (json_serializado, textStatus, xhr) ->
        id_envio = String(this.id_envio)
        id_barra_progresso = String(this.id_barra_progresso)

        console.log "Rodou .done em get_job_status()"

        interpret_job_result id_envio, id_barra_progresso, '', 'envio_emails_agrupado', json_serializado



window.interpret_job_result = (id_operacao, id_barra_progresso, nome_arquivo_pai, tipo_operacao, json_serializado) ->

    console.log 'tipo_operacao in interpret_job_result(): "' + tipo_operacao + '", ID da operacao "' + id_operacao + '".'

    $selector_barra_progresso = $('#' + id_barra_progresso)

    if tipo_operacao == 'envio_emails_agrupado'
        funcao_verificacao_resultados = get_job_status(id_operacao, id_barra_progresso, nome_arquivo_pai, tipo_operacao)
    else
        funcao_verificacao_resultados = verifica_status_job_relatorio(id_operacao, id_barra_progresso, nome_arquivo_pai, tipo_operacao)


    try
        json_object = JSON.parse(json_serializado)
    catch erro
        json_object = {}

        console.log 'ERRO ao tentar realizar parse do JSON recebido do servidor Pyhon. Referente a operacao "' + tipo_operacao + '",
                com ID "' + id_operacao + '", arquivo "' + nome_arquivo_pai + '"\nConteudo JSON: ' + JSON.stringify(json_serializado)

        $selector_barra_progresso.width '100%'
        $selector_barra_progresso.text "ERRO!"
        $selector_barra_progresso.removeClass()
        $selector_barra_progresso.addClass "progress-bar progress-bar-custom-vermelho"

        window.contadorErros[id_operacao] += 1

        unless window.contadorErros[id_operacao] > 5
            setTimeout (-> window[funcao_verificacao_resultados]), 2000
        else
            erro = 'Ocorreram 5 erros consecutivos no parse do JSON recebido do backend Python, referente a verificacao' +
                'do status da operacao "' + tipo_operacao + '" com ID: "' + id_operacao + '".'

            console.log(erro)

            exibe_erros(id_operacao, '', id_barra_progresso, tipo_operacao, erro)


    status_processamento = json_object.status
    erros_processamento = json_object.erros_e_warnings
    nome_arquivo_gerado = json_object.nome_arquivo_gerado
    progresso_percent = json_object.progresso_percent


    if status_processamento is "sucess"
        console.log 'Operacao "' + tipo_operacao + '" com ID "' + id_operacao + '" (arquivo pai: ' + nome_arquivo_pai + ') concluido com SUCESSO.'

        $selector_barra_progresso.width '100%'
        $selector_barra_progresso.text "Concluído"
        $selector_barra_progresso.removeClass()
        $selector_barra_progresso.addClass "progress-bar progress-bar-custom-verde"

    else if status_processamento is "fail"
        console.log 'Operacao "' + tipo_operacao + '" com ID "' + id_operacao + '" (arquivo pai: ' + nome_arquivo_pai + ') FALHOU.'

        exibe_erros(id_operacao, nome_arquivo_pai, id_barra_progresso, tipo_operacao, erros_processamento)


    else if status_processamento is "running"
        console.log 'Job "' + tipo_operacao + '" com ID "' + id_operacao + '" (arquivo pai: ' + nome_arquivo_pai + ') RODANDO. '

        $selector_barra_progresso.width progresso_percent + '%'
        $selector_barra_progresso.text progresso_percent.toString() + '%'

        $selector_barra_progresso.removeClass()
        $selector_barra_progresso.addClass "progress-bar progress-bar-custom-verde active"

        setTimeout (-> window[funcao_verificacao_resultados]), 1000
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you,
Bruno

Answer (score 0):

Typoproblem *if status_processamento is "sucess"* -> *if status_processamento is "su`c`cess"*

Answer (score 0):

If found the problem, it was here:

```
   if tipo_operacao == 'envio_emails_agrupado'
    funcao_verificacao_resultados = get_job_status(id_operacao, id_barra_progresso, nome_arquivo_pai, tipo_operacao)
else
    funcao_verificacao_resultados = verifica_status_job_relatorio(id_operacao, id_barra_progresso, nome_arquivo_pai, tipo_operacao)
```

The goal of the above lines of code was to "switch" between 2 functions depending on the value of tipo_operacao (I know, not pretty). However the syntax is wrong and the functions get_job_status and verifica_status_job_relatorio were being wrongly executed. These functions were calling other functions and all hell broke loose.